# Windows Subsystem Linux cgroup issues with slurmd

Tags: mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cluster, cgroup

I am trying to add my computer running Ubuntu WSL to a slurm cluster I have, made up of old laptops. And when I run 
`sudo service slurmd start` 
it comes back as failed. I checked the /var/log/slurmd.log I get the following output.

```
[2021-09-07T14:35:43.776] Message aggregation disabled
[2021-09-07T14:35:43.796] error: unable to mount freezer cgroup namespace: Invalid argument
[2021-09-07T14:35:43.796] error: unable to create freezer cgroup namespace
[2021-09-07T14:35:43.796] error: Couldn't load specified plugin name for proctrack/cgroup: Plugin init() callback failed
[2021-09-07T14:35:43.796] error: cannot create proctrack context for proctrack/cgroup
[2021-09-07T14:35:43.796] error: slurmd initialization failed
```

I had a similar issue when I tried to start the slurm daemon on the stand alone laptops, but the issue went away when I generated the cgroup.conf file and co-located it with my slurm.conf file. I did the same on the WSL machine and it still is throwing these errors. Freezer does exist at /sys/fs/cgroup so whatever mount command is being used under the hood just doesn't seem to take. I tried installing cgroup-tools but it still didn't work. From what I've been able to gather from some google searches, cgroups are not implemented in WSL, even though it exists in the location above. Does anyone know of a workaround or a fix for this? Some extra step to get this working? Or is it a lost cause?

Thanks!